# Css-Jquery with And Condition

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

I want to bind two css selector with and operator
 For example:

```
$( 'input[class*="ng-invalid"]  input[type="number"]')
```

it means $( 'input[class*="ng-invalid"]) &&(input[type="number"]')

But it does not return any result however I have.

Comment: You should not use jQuery on the top of AngularJS. AngularJS digest cycle wont run if you do any DOM manipulation or scope variable manipulation using JQuery.

Comment: what does it have to do with digest cycle? @Magicprog.fr

Comment: How can I check classes while validating my inputs

Comment: @kle that is another question? ask with a post.

Answer (score 1):

Just comma separate the selectors like you would in normal CSS:

```
$('input[class*="ng-invalid"], input[type="number"]')
```

jQuery uses CSS selectors to get elements.

Comment: No, only as AND. You'd have to script an if statement or a case switch to use OR functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[class*="ng-invalid"][type="number"]');
```

Comment: $( 'input[class*="ng-invalid"][type="number"]') works as And, OTher one is working like "OR"

Comment: Ok Thanks, got a bit confused there ;)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: This question has been asked multiple times before and answered elaborately. Should be flagged as duplicate